# HackerRank segmentation fault while merging two sorted linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, c++14, singly-linked-list

Two sorted linked lists are given. The task is to merge both of the list (in-place) and return head of the merged list.
This code seems to work for some cases and gives Segmentation fault when submitted on HackerRank.
I assign one list as the 'tail' pointer which traverses till the end. And the nodes of the 'other' list are added to (in between) the tail list when required.
That part looks like this:

```
struct Node *temp=new Node(other->data);
temp->next=tail;
prev->next=temp;
prev=temp;
other=other->next;
```

The full code is here:

```
Node* sortedMerge(Node* a, Node* b)  
    {  
        // code here
        if(a==NULL)return b;
        if(b==NULL)return a;
        Node *tail,*other,*prev=NULL,*head;
        if(a->data<b->data)
        {
            head=a;
            tail=a;other=b;
        }
        else{
            head=b;
            tail=b;other=a;
        }
        while(other!=NULL && tail!=NULL)
        {
            if(tail->data < other->data)
            {
                prev=tail;
                tail=tail->next;
            }
            else{
                struct Node *temp=new Node(other->data);
                temp->next=tail;
                prev->next=temp;
                prev=temp;
                other=other->next;
            }
        }
         while(tail!=NULL)
        {
            prev->next=tail;
            prev=tail;
            tail=tail->next;
        }
        while(other!=NULL)
        {
            prev->next=other;
            prev=other;
            other=other->next;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]. What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: You're not handling empty lists.

Comment: "In-place" means that you are supposed to just use the nodes of the inputs, not create any new nodes.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm sorry but how does it matter? It might give segmentation fault?

Comment: Merging "in place" is the entire point of this exercise. If you're creating new nodes, you're not solving the problem.

Comment: we still need a [mre]

Comment: `a->data == b->data`, your program dereferences `prev` in `prev->next=temp` while `prev` is still null.